# How to plot three histograms adjacent to each other for 3 given series?

Tags: r, histogram

I have one data table (tab separated) as follows.

data.csv

```
A   B   C
0.0509259   0.0634984   0.0334984
0.12037 0.0599042   0.0299042
0.00925926  0.0109824   0.0599042
0.990741    0.976837    0.059442
0.99537 0.997404    0.0549042
0.99537 0.997404    0.0529042
0.00462963  0.0109824   0.0699042
0.986111    0.975839    0.0999042
0.12963 0.0758786   0.0899042
0.00462963  0.00419329  0.0499042
0.865741    0.876597    0.0519042
0.865741    0.870807    0.0539042
```

How can i plot multiseries data in one histogram as explained below.

```
data<-read.table("C:/Users/User/Desktop/data.csv",header=T)

hist(data$A)
hist(data$B)
hist(data$C)
```

how can i merge these three histogram together in a way that i can see three diffrernt series together in different colors in one plot?

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: What do the colors represent in your sample? Are those groups (A,B,C) or numeric bins? What would be labeled along the x-axis?

Comment: colors represent A,B,C. Along x-axis bins will be labelled

Comment: It is unclear what is you x axis here. How do decide on bins. For example, if you cut your whole data set into 3 bins, all the value in `C` will be always in the same bin because they vary very little compared to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways. In base R:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(data)),beside=TRUE,
        col=c("red","green","blue"),names=rownames(data))
```

[image]

Using `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
gg <- melt(data.frame(id=rownames(data),data),id="id")
gg$id <- factor(gg$id,levels=unique(gg$id))
ggplot(gg,aes(x=id,y=value,fill=variable))+geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

The `ggplot` approach, which ultimately is much more flexible, is also more work. You have to add a column based on the row names (or a sequence `1:nrow(data)`, if you prefer), and convert the data from wide to long format (as in the other answer). But you're still not done: `ggplot` converts the id's to a factor and then orders them alphabetically, so the groups are, e,g, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, ... You don't want that, so you have to reorder the factor first, and then plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok with ggplot2, you can do it as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
```

1: Rearrange the dataframe to change A,B,C, to factors:

```
dat3 <- melt(dat2, varnames = c('A','B','C'))
```

2: Plot using the factors:  (

```
qplot(data=dat3, value, fill=variable, position = 'dodge')
```

Can't say too many good things about [ggplot2](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)

[image]

Comment: I was thinking the same at the beginning, but where are the 3 plots? This is all together here